# Setting up LaTeX to compile elsewhere?

Tags: latex, atom-editor, tex, texlive

How can I set up a compile server and editing client on different machines?

### Context

I use my netbook for document editing, but it doesn't have the storage space to run a full TeX distribution. It is running Windows 10, and I primarily use [Atom](https://atom.io/) for editing. I also have an HTPC running Ubuntu, with `ssh`, `tex-live` and a `samba` fileshare.

### Problem

I want to edit `tex` files on my netbook, have them compiled on the HTPC, and view the resultant PDFs back on the netbook just as if they had been compiled locally. [`synctex`](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/118491/155575) would be a bonus.

#### Solutions?

Since I didn't find any programs which fit the bill on my (admittedly brief) Internet perusal, I have considered a number of more fiddly solutions:

- Reconfigure Atom's [`latex`](https://atom.io/packages/latex) package somehow to use the HTPC for compilation
- Create a local script which purports to locally compile documents, but essentially acts as a gateway to the HTPC's distribution
- Save the `tex` files to the HTPC via `samba`, and set up the compiler there to watch it for changes
- Do the same thing as above, but in reverse (so the HTPC accesses the files on the netbook and compiles them)

Comment: Related: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/49946/setting-up-your-own-latex-compile-server

Comment: N.B. since this question is more about the networking and scripting of the two computers than about LaTeX itself, I was split between posting here and on superuser. Feel free to vote for/flag it as such if you think it should be moved there.

Comment: Almost certainly belongs at Superuser, not here. By the way, do online services such as ShareLatex and Overleaf not work for you?

Comment: I have used both without issue for the past few months, but I need a little more flexibility - for example, both services time out after around 10 CPU secs of compilation; and neither work well with custom packages. (Is there any way to migrate the question, other than flagging it and waiting for a mod?)

Comment: This would be straightforward if both machines ran some unix-ish OS (Linux, one of the BSD, Apple's Darwin or whatever). Then you just forward X. Clueless about Windows, though. I guess it is certainly not going to have the kind of designed-in-fundamentally features which come out-of-the-box with X. (Well X and some other bits and pieces to make the file stuff all work out nicely and secure the connection.)

Comment: I don't think you can do more than flag and wait. There's no migration route from this site to SU.

Comment: One other note: although I use and/or browse SE sites quite frequently, I rarely ask questions - and when I do, I tend to make them overly specific to my use-case. Please feel free to suggest edits to the question so that it is more likely to be found by others in applicable scenarios.